# Invoke self hosted WCF from jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf

I have a self hosted WCF through a windows service. I am trying to call a method in service but its not working. I can see following error in google chrome console

> OPTIONS http://localhost:9093/Service1/method1
>
> ```
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9093/Service1/method1. Invalid HTTP status code 400
> ```

this is my jQuery code

```
var url = 'http://localhost:9093/Service1/method1';
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: { identifire: identifire },
                    type: 'POST',
                    global: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: callbacks.success,
                    error: function () { }
                })
```

here is my contract

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        void method1(string identifire);
```

here is the config file

```
 <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webSupport">
          <webHttp />

        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service name="IService1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:9093/Service1" behaviorConfiguration="webSupport"
            binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

this is how I start my service inside OnStart event of my windows service

```
string hostAddress = "http://localhost:9093/Service1";

        Uri[] addresses = { new Uri(hostAddress) };

        scanHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1),addresses);
        scanHost.Open();
```

BTW when I invoke this method using a Service reference from ASP.net it works fine. I only get issues when trying to call this from jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Change your endpoint tag like this

```
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webSupport"
        binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IService1" />
```

Also your url should be like this

```
var url = 'http://localhost:9093/Service1.svc/method1';
```

And data should be like this

```
data: JSON.stringify({identifire: identifire}),
```

Comment: What is value of identifire ?